# Why cant I use a variable in str slicing?

Tags: python

So I answered one of the questions on Coding Bat that asked to return half of a string n number of times by defining a variable that takes half the length of the original string and using that variable in slicing the string.

Coding bat accepted the result, but when I try to recreate the problem on Jupyter Notebook it only accepts "integers or None or *index* method".

What am I doing wrong?

Im a beginner in Python and just want to make sure that I'm learning the correct format.

```
def first_half(str):
  newword = len(str) / 2
  return '{}'.format(str[:newword])
```

for `first_half('Milkshakes')` I expect to get `'Milk'`. 
However, the error im getting is:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because `len(str) / 2` gives you a float value `5.0` and you cannot use a float as a argument to string slice, convert the argument to an int by doing `int(len(str) / 2)`, which gives you `5`, and it should work. Note that the above only holds true for `Python 3` the original code you have still works for `Python 2` where you don't need the `float` to `int` conversion

Also `str` is a python builtin, so it's bad practice to use it as a variable.

In addition, you want the first half of `Milkshakes` is `Milks`, and not `Milk`

```
def first_half(s):
    #Parse float to int
    newword = int(len(s) / 2)
    return '{}'.format(s[:newword])

print(first_half('Milkshakes'))
#Milks
```

To make a generic solution, as some of the commentors have suggested, you can use integer division `//`, which works for both `Python 2` and `Python 3`

```
def first_half(s):
    #Integer division
    newword = len(s) // 2
    return '{}'.format(s[:newword])

print(first_half('Milkshakes'))
```

Comment: Hi @seifSherif, glad to help! Please consider accepting my answer if it helped you :)